# Don't click item in tableviewrow titanium

Tags: click, titanium, tableview

I create a tableview and tableviewrows is customized.In item rows,has text and image..If I click text or image,will get event click row of tableview but if i click outside them,i can't get event click..Can you help me.

Comment: Can you post your eventlistener code please.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this :
"singletap" is also working like "click".

```
tableview.addeventListener('singletap',function(evt){
   alert("Event occur : "+ evt);

});
```

For more info click [here](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/1.2/Titanium.UI.TableView-object)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
table.addeventListener('singletap',function(evnt){
     alert("Event occur :- ");

});
```